# update component when progress value changes

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a progress bar that shows the percentage, the problem Im having is that it is not updating correctly, Im trying to get it to load from 0 after half a second and then display the `$progress` value as it increases, however at the moment it initially jumps to around 50% but then stays there and doesn't update any further.

How can I get it to show the updated progress?

```
<script>  

import { progress } from '../../store';

let width = 0

setTimeout(() => width = $progress, 500)

$: animatedWidth = width

</script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="line">
        <div class="animation" style="width: {animatedWidth}%"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you update with the store file to see your progress variable ? and I don't see any update of the value.

Comment: the $progress variable goes from 0 to 100 over a minute or so, this is working fine , it is getting this value, just the component is not refreshing automatically, if the page is reloaded it will jump to the correct position

Comment: Well, `setTimeout` is only going to update `width` once, and that update will occur 500ms  after the code loads & executes, but possibly before the component is even mounted, resulting in no *visual* updates. You should use `setInterval` with a smaller duration (repeated, more frequent updates), and move it into Svelte's `onMount` lifecycle method so that updating only starts after the component is actually mounted and visible. Use Svelte's `destroy` lifecycle function to do cleanup (`clearInterval`).

Comment: Alternatively, if your store is already simulating progress over time, don't use `setTimeout` at all, and instead directly map the width to the store value `style="width: {$progress}%"`.

Comment: it is directly simulating over time however I need to add a delay before the animation starts, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. I created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9e86f2af7f4e4b5380ed176f0f04dbd7?version=3.22.3) for you with the following code:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let width = 0;
  let interval;

  onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      width = 1;
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (width <= 100) {
          width += 1;
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }, 500);
  });

  $: animatedWidth = width;
</script>
```

What you basically do is use setTimeout to start the animation after a delay of 500ms. After that, it will update the width until 100 is reached, then it will end the interval. To make things easier for the example I used 1 as a starting value, but you could easily do this with your imported store value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use tweened stores if you wanted to have it animated without CSS, it is pretty straightforward, here is a REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/6ef1130a13f641f2bf72c67a16ea429f?version=3.22.3

```
<script>
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';
import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
import { cubicOut } from 'svelte/easing';

const time = readable(new Date(), function start(set) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        set(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return function stop() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
});

const width = tweened(0, {
    duration: 300,
    easing: cubicOut,
    delay: 3000
});

let started = false;

$: if(started) {
    width.set($time.getSeconds());
}
</script>

<p>
    {$width}
</p>
{#if !started}
    <button on:click={() => started = true}>
        Start
    </button>
{/if}
```

I have created the `time` store as a replacement for your store (as you didn't provide the code for it). The `width` store is the important part, it delays its first update by 3 secs and then just keeps updating. Obviously, once it hits its limit, it will go to 0, as there are only 60 seconds in a minute. ;) You just need to subscribe to the `time` store: `width.set($time.getSeconds());`

So basically all you have to do is to import the tweened store and use:

```
const width = tweened(0, {
    duration: 300,
    delay: 500
});

width.set($progress);
```

And then set your elements width to `{$width}`.